# Fast bounding of data in R

Tags: performance, r, data.table, bigdata, rcpp

Suppose I have a vector, `vec`, which is long (starting at 1E8 entries) and would like to bound it to the range `[a,b]`.  I can certainly code `vec[vec < a] = a` and `vec[vec > b] = b`, but this requires two passes over the data and a large RAM allocation for the temporary indicator vector (~800MB, twice).  The two passes burn time because we can do better if we copy data from main memory to the local cache just once (calls to main memory are bad, as are cache misses).  And who knows how much this could be improved with multiple threads, but let's not get greedy.  :)

Is there a nice implementation in base R or some package that I'm overlooking, or is this a job for Rcpp (or my old friend `data.table`)?

Answer (score 13):

A naive C solution is

```
library(inline)

fun4 <-
    cfunction(c(x="numeric", a="numeric", b="numeric"), body4,
              language="C")
body4 <- "
    R_len_t len = Rf_length(x);
    SEXP result = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, len);
    const double aa = REAL(a)[0], bb = REAL(b)[0], *xp = REAL(x);
    double *rp = REAL(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (xp[i] < aa)
            rp[i] = aa;
        else if (xp[i] > bb)
            rp[i] = bb;
        else
            rp[i] = xp[i];

    return result;
"
fun4 <-
    cfunction(c(x="numeric", a="numeric", b="numeric"), body4,
              language="C")
```

With a simple parallel version (as Dirk points out, this is with `CFLAGS = -fopenmp` in ~/.R/Makevars, and on a platform / compiler supporting openmp)

```
body5 <- "
    R_len_t len = Rf_length(x);
    const double aa = REAL(a)[0], bb = REAL(b)[0], *xp = REAL(x);
    SEXP result = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, len);
    double *rp = REAL(result);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (xp[i] < aa)
            rp[i] = aa;
        else if (xp[i] > bb)
            rp[i] = bb;
        else
            rp[i] = xp[i];

    return result;
"
fun5 <-
    cfunction(c(x="numeric", a="numeric", b="numeric"), body5,
              language="C")
```

And benchmarks

```
> z <- runif(1e7)
> benchmark(fun1(z,0.25,0.75), fun4(z, .25, .75), fun5(z, .25, .75),
+           replications=10)
                 test replications elapsed  relative user.self sys.self
1 fun1(z, 0.25, 0.75)           10   9.087 14.609325     8.335    0.739
2 fun4(z, 0.25, 0.75)           10   1.505  2.419614     1.305    0.198
3 fun5(z, 0.25, 0.75)           10   0.622  1.000000     2.156    0.320
  user.child sys.child
1          0         0
2          0         0
3          0         0
> identical(res1 <- fun1(z,0.25,0.75), fun4(z,0.25,0.75))
[1] TRUE
> identical(res1, fun5(z, 0.25, 0.75))
[1] TRUE
```

on my quad-core laptop. Assumes numeric input, no error checking, NA handling, etc.

Comment: +1 I'd like this function in core R, called something like `clamp(x, low, high)`... Well one can always wish, right ;-)

Comment: +1 for OpenMP, but I think you need to modify PKG_CFLAGS etc to get `-fopenmp`. Or did you do so somewhere else, eg in `~/.R/Makevars` ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel R's configure.ac detects OpenMP; `-fopenmp` is set in R_HOME/etc/Makeconf.

Comment: Not on my machine, I get `warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]` from your example.  Even though I have `-fopenmp` in `/etc/R/Makeconf` (which is a symlink to the location below `R_HOME`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yes you're right, ~/.R/Makevars contains `CFLAGS = -fopenmp`

Answer (score 3):

Just to start things off: not much difference between your solution and the `pmin`/`pmax` solution (trying things out with n=1e7 rather than n=1e8 because I'm impatient) -- `pmin`/`pmax` is actually marginally slower.

```
fun1 <- function(x,a,b) {x[x<a] <- a; x[x>b] <- b; x}
fun2 <- function(x,a,b) pmin(pmax(x,a),b)
library(rbenchmark)
z <- runif(1e7)

benchmark(fun1(z,0.25,0.75),fun2(z,0.25,0.75),rep=50)

                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 fun1(z, 0.25, 0.75)           10  21.607  1.00000     6.556   15.001
2 fun2(z, 0.25, 0.75)           10  23.336  1.08002     5.656   17.605
```

Comment: Interesting.  I was hopeful that that would be faster, but it seems no such luck.

Comment: `fun2` is about 20% faster for me on R version 2.15.0 Patched (2012-05-01 r59304) Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit) compiled with CFLAGS=-O0; the hack `.Internal(pmin(FALSE, x, a))` etc is about 30% faster than `fun1`.